Xcode error on Github action: Could not determine generated file paths for Core Data code generation:
I don't know why the xcdatamodeld I added to my Xcode project is always missing when I try to build the project on CI or another machine and keep getting the error: Could not determine generated file paths for Core Data code generation:
I tried creating a new Xcode project and added xcdatamodeld, project builds successfully but when I send the new project to another Mac it doesn't build until I remove the file and re-add it manually to the folder.
I have tried all suggestions from this answer - Swift error: Could not determine generated file paths for Core Data code generation: and this - Could not determine generated file paths for CoreData code generation but nothing has worked for me so far. Difference is that I don't have any issues building on my local machine but on other machines without having to manually add the file.
Any idea how to resolve this because I can't manually add the file on CI.
I also tried adding the file to the target compile sources on CI using a script inspired by this - https://github.com/hovox/xcodeproj-add-files/blob/master/addfile.rb but still failing:

I was able to solve this by changing the path of the .xcdatamodeld file by editing the project.pbxproj file in VSCode from an absolute path to a relative path:
);
        currentVersion = 20F3D6F52C25F5C100B32751 /* Model.xcdatamodel */;
        name = Model.xcdatamodeld;
        path = "/Users/username/Desktop/.../.../.../Models/Model.xcdatamodeld";
        sourceTree = "<group>";
        versionGroupType = wrapper.xcdatamodel;
    };

So I replaced the absolute path with path = "Model.xcdatamodeld";
I think a bug in Xcode is causing this to happen even when the file is added from new file dialog.
This might be useful to someone else.

Confirmed. I suggest you report this to Apple. This file is the only one in the project that is referenced by absolute path. This was not the case for projects created in earlier versions of Xcode; for example, an older project of mine has path = Diary_DataModel.xcdatamodeld; by default.

@matt Yeah I already contacted Apple about it before I found a solution and I explained it isn't happening with projects created with older Xcode versions.

That's splendid, thank you so much for doing that. You've found a clear bug and Apple should fix it.

Also let's emphasize that the problem here isn't just a matter of copying the project to another machine; you can't move the project folder at all (i.e. to another folder, such as, from the Desktop to some other location) because of this bug.
